# How do I logout from Youtube?

Tags: google-account, youtube, android-10

I have multiple Google accounts on my Android 10 (Samsung Galaxy M10s). Until today, I was using YouTube without signing in. Today I signed into YouTube with one Google account. Now I want to sign out from YouTube app but I don't find any such option.

I searched on internet and found [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3802431?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en-GB) which suggests to remove account from device in order to sign-out from YouYube app.

What I did:

Opened YouTube, go to manage accounts, removed the account from device, through which I have signed in YouTube; Then cleared the YouTube application data also.

But what I found is YouTube just auto signed in with my another Google account.

How do I sign out from YouTube?

Comment: I would assume that as long as one Google account is registered on your device the YouTube app will use it. The only chance I see is using a n alternative YouTube app like NewPipe [available for example on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/).

Comment: @Robert Yes I mostly use NewPipe. I used YouTube app for commenting on one Video.

Comment: I think it should be possible to revert to yesterday's state which is I had been YouTube without signing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the logout option is not available but after clearing the app data, the logout option becomes available.

Before clearing app data:

[image]

After clearing app data:

[image]

So, the solution that worked for me is: **Clear the app data to make the Logout option available.**

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser to get onto Youtube.
Log in, using the account you want to have logged out.

Then use the 3 dot menu to sign out.

Now clear the data in your Youtube app.

(I also think that you can sign out with the settings in the Youtube app, but I can't say how as I don't use the app.)

Comment: No, Logging out from browser doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sign out from the Youtube app by downgrading it to a lower version via adb (I used 14.39.55), signing out and reinstalling the newest version.

1. Force stop the Youtube app if already running
2. Clean its internal data and cache
3. Download the older Youtube app on your PC. Source: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-14-39-55-release/youtube-14-39-55-android-apk-download/
4. Connect your phone to the PC, activate developer mode and enable USB debugging. Check if adb sees the phone by typing `adb devices`
5. Install the apk via the command `adb install -d 'com.google.android.youtube_14.39.55-1439552000_minAPI19(arm64-v8a)(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk'`
6. Open the Youtube app. It won't be able to connect to the server, but you should be able to click on your account logo on the top right and see the “Sign out” button. Click it.
7. Re-update the Youtube app to the current version. You should now be logged out.